# Java - ArrayList - Getting acces to objects field

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

how can I get acces to a field of an object in an ArrayList, when the object extends the type I wrote in the ArrayList generics ?

Heres the code:

```
ArrayList<ObjectA> objA = new ArrayList()<>;
objA.add( new ObjectA() );  
objA.add( new ObjectAB() ); // ObjectAB extends ObjectA
```

now I would like to change the variablein ObjectAB, stored in the list

( only ObjectAB has this field, not ObjectA )

Comment: What do you mean by `only ObjectAB has this field, not ObjectA`?

Comment: @Masud He added some more fields in the extended class ObjectAB; and he is trying to access them. Ofcourse reference of type ObjectA cannot show the newly added fields in its child class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
ArrayList<ObjectA> objA = new ArrayList()<>;
objA.add( new ObjectA() );  
objA.add( new ObjectAB() ); // ObjectAB extends ObjectA

ObjectAB ab = (ObjectAB) objA.get(1);
ab.setFieldFromAB("foo");
```

So you have to cast item from list objA to type ObjectAB. If you are not sure the cast will succeed you might want to do some checks first like

```
if(objA.get(1) instanceof ObjectAB) {
   ObjectAB ab = (ObjectAB) objA.get(1);
   ab.setFieldFromAB("foo");
} else {
   //doSomethingElse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve back objects from the `ArrayList`, you will get Objects of type `ObjectA` only.
Because `ArrayList<T>` is the list of `T` type objects.

```
ObjectA obj0 = objA.get(0);
ObjectA obj1 = objA.get(1);   // This you cannot get as the reference of ObjectAB
```

You need to explicitly downcast `obj1` to `ObjectAB`

```
ObjectAB obj1B = (ObjectAB) obj1;
```

However if you really require explicit downcasting, then you are defeating the very purpose of the Generics - type safety. For sure there would be some better ways.